# Select max values, but when ties, select max from other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max

I have a table with columns `id, cl_id, ratio, diff` and I want to select the observations with max `ratio`, grouped by `cl_id`, but if there are equal values, then it should be selected the max `diff` from the equals.

Below are the `Have` and `Want` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Have(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    cl_id CHAR(1),
    ratio DECIMAL(5,4),
    diff INT
);

INSERT INTO Have(id, cl_id, ratio, diff) VALUES 
(122222, 'a', 1.3333, 2),
(123333, 'a', 1.3333, 5),
(124444, 'b', 1.25, 2),
(125555, 'b', 1.6667, 1);


CREATE TABLE Want(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    cl_id CHAR(1),
    ratio DECIMAL(5,4),
    diff INT
);

INSERT INTO Want(id, cl_id, ratio, diff) VALUES 
(123333, 'a', 1.3333, 5),
(125555, 'b', 1.6667, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here with a two level sort:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cl_id ORDER BY ratio DESC, diff DESC) rn
    FROM Have
)

SELECT id, cl_id, ratio, diff
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```